# I need backups to start with a deny policy in place

Tags: azure, backup, snapshot, policy

I have a few policies in place to govern Snapshot creation and backup creation. What I need is to be able to create a backup in a specific recovery service vault for all VMs created within the Subscription.

The problem I am having is not with the built in policy of creating the backup, but in the automatic process of performing the backup. When performing the initial backup, a snapshot is temporarily created. With the custom policy in place, the snapshot creation is failing. **Is there a way to set the type of storage account for the initial snapshot during backup?** I have the policies below in place.

Policies:

[Built-in]Configure backup on virtual machines with a given tag to an existing recovery services vault in the same location

[Custom]Require Standard HDD storage type on Snapshots

- This policy Denys the creation of any Snapshot unless it is a Standard LRS Storage type.

The backup works fine once the snapshot policy is removed, but I have to have this policy in place.